# When JSON data is included in a Node.js file with require() is it treated as a generic object or a special case?

Tags: node.js, json

When `JSON` data is imported into `Node.js` using `require()` it appears to function like a generic object.  For example the code below works as expected.

```
const jsonData = require('./randomData.json');

for(property in jsonData) {
    console.log(property);
}
```

However has the imported `JSON` become a generic object or is it a special case?  For example JS includes `arrays`, and also `array-like objects`.  Is it something like that?

Comment: It is [treated](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `require('./randomData.json')` is the same as if you had done `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('./randomData.json')))` that is the return value has already been parsed. The main effect of using require rather than this is that the json is cached in the modules array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about JSON.parse, the imported object is json, but JSON.parse takes a string as a parameter and converts it to json, you are giving it json as the parameter.

Comment: Whoops!  Ok you're right, I did that backwards.  I better fix that in the question.

Comment: As to using require to import json, the result (jsonData) is a plain old JS object. The only thing to watch out for is that require will only read the file once, then cache the results, so if you change the file further down, those changes will not be reflected if you require it again.